# Fastest way to calculate a heavy function between elements of two different lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension, permutation, python-itertools

As written in the title I would like to know if there is a faster way than the one I found to perform a computationally complex function between elements of two lists.

Here as an example I will take the factorial but the function is a dynamo function that checks if there are intersections between two elements.

This is what I've been able to do so far. Can anyone help me?

```
%%time
import random
import itertools
import math
random.seed(10)

list1=[random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(10000)]
list2=[random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(100)]

two_lists=[list1,list2]
permutation = itertools.product(*two_lists) # I obtain the permutation ty Cyttorak
result=[math.factorial(x[0]+x[1]) for x in permutation] # The complex operation (factorial of the sum)
```

```
Wall time: 1.11 s
```

Comment: Right off the bat, you can remove the `list` call in the second last line, instead use, `permutation = itertools.product(*two_lists)`

Comment: ...also, depending on your parameters maybe `functools.lru_cache` will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only get a 8x speed up with getting rid off the indexing, redundant lists and caching computations. `maxsize` is taylored for your example.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def facto(x):
    return math.factorial(x)

result=[facto(x+y) for x,y in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: Wow dude is impressive. Can you explain me better what are you doing? and how I can chose maxsize?

Comment: You create numbers up to 100 and up to 10, so max ist 100+10. The next larger power of 2 is 128. That's my cache size. `@lru_cache` adds a 'memory' for past calls to the function and returns for known arguments the results of the computation from this memory.

Comment: Strictly speaking `maxsize=None` would be the optimal solution and a little bit faster, because we know the number of unique calls. `maxsize` is only necessary if you have a large number of distinct calls and want to limit the memory usage. In such cases, it can be beneficial to sort your calls by argument to get the most cache hits.

Answer (score 2):

In the original question, a list (*result*) of factorials is created even though it's not apparently used. This code is consistent with that anomaly and typically executes in ~0.11s on my machine :-

```
import random
from math import factorial
from itertools import product
import time
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=110)
def facto(n):
    return factorial(n)


start = time.perf_counter()
list1 = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(10000)]
list2 = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(100)]
result = [facto(x) for x in map(sum, product(list1, list2))]
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end-start)
```

With thanks to Michael Szczesny for idea to use lru_cache

Comment: Nice improve we have 496 ms but @Michael Szczesny get 169 ms

Comment: Yes - lru_cache is new to me. I just tried that and I get ~0.11s

Answer (score 1):

This will do the same work repeatedly since you pick very often from very small pools. You can cache results, e.g. using a `dict`:

```
list1=[random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(10000)]
list2=[random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(100)]

cache = {}

result=[cache.get(s, factorial(s)) for s in map(sum, product(list1, list2))]
```

Comment: But nothing gets added to the *cache* dictionary so I don't see how this helps

Comment: I get a small improve it takes: Wall time: 1.04 s. But often I have worst results. Can we do better?

Answer (score 1):

If the function is computationally complex, it is a waste of time to optimize the loop that constructs the list element combinations. Just make sure that

(a) each distinct combination of elements is only evaluated once, and

(b) if the function lends itself to calculating recursively, reimplement the calculation to save time (e.g., with factorial you would cache smaller values and use them for the bigger numbers.)